# jQuery prepend() not working, what is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm confused my append() not showing up in the HTML. Can you guys tell me what is wrong in the following code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="password">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputError"> Password:</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="input-password" placeholder="Password" value="" name="password"/>
</div>
```

my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[name="password"]').focusout(function() {
            if($(this).val()==""){
                $('#password').attr('class','form-group has-error');
                $('#password .control-label').prepend("<span class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></span>");
                $('#password .control-label').text(' Input your new password!');
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Put your jquery code inside jquery document ready function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the focusout event is triggered, the problem is you are using .text() after .prepend() which will remove the content added with .prepend()

```
$('input[name="password"]').focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $('#password').attr('class', 'form-group has-error');
        $('#password .control-label').text(' Input your new password!');
        $('#password .control-label').prepend("<span class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></span>");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8s477aa5/)

---

So

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('input[name="password"]').focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $('#password').attr('class', 'form-group has-error');
            $('#password .control-label').text(' Input your new password!').prepend("<span class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></span>");
            //$('#password .control-label').html('<span class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span> Input your new password!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: oh, thanks! I didn't know this cause the problem, I spent an hour solving this error.